# udev rule for non-root users unbinding pci drivers?

Tags: udev

I'm trying to write a set of udev rules to allow a user in a group kvm to unbind drivers on a pci device. The commands in question are:

```
echo '0000:0b:00.0' > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/driver/unbind
echo 0x1912 0x0014 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id
```

I'd like to be able to execute these as a user in the kvm group, I've had no luck so far. I originally tried setting the group on the device itself, then both the xhci_hcd and vfio-pci drivers, using variations of the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="pci", ATTR{vendor}=="0x1912", ATTR{device}=="0x0014", OWNER="root", GROUP="kvm"
KERNEL=="xhci_hcd", SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", OWNER="root", GROUP="kvm"
KERNEL=="vfio-pci", SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", OWNER="root", GROUP="kvm"
```

But these have had no effect, I even tried setting the group on the entire subsytems just to test and there were no permission changes, so I assume I'm doing something entirely wrong.

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if the question itself doesn't expect specific results that can make getting your answer harder than easier.

First: you should use "udevadm info -a -p /sys/devices/" to check whether KERNEL/SUBSYSTEM attributes that you tried using are really the ones used by kernel.

Second: if it finally matches you could just run your rebinding commands from udev rules directly.

Here's an example based on http://vogelchr.blogspot.com/2016/02/linuxudev-unbinding-from-one-kernel.html that I modified for my PCI device (namely NVMe SSD) as the binding mechanism behaves differently for me on 4.15+ kernel.

udev rule: `DRIVER=="nvme", ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0xa801",ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x144d", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/rebind_pci_driver.sh %k vfio-pci"`

And the script that we call:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
logger -t "$0" "Rebind device $1 to driver $2."
echo "$1" >"/sys/bus/pci/devices/$1/driver/unbind"
sleep 1
echo "$1" >"/sys/bus/pci/drivers/$2/bind"
```